# Stop iPod music by NSTimer on background mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, ipod, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm planning to create an application that plays the ipod Music Library, then the app sets a NSTimer that will stop the ipod Music player on a certain time. My question does my timer will still run when I entered the background mode. Is it possible to stop the ipod Music player on background Mode?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
[timer invalidate]
```

use this in your code.